# How to get an array that meets a certain condition and remove blanks?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a list of employees in Google sheet with their work start and end dates. It looks like this (sample):

[image]

I need to generate a new list out of it, that will have employees, who were employed during a particular month, say February 2018.

In that case the list should look like:

[image]

How do I do that? Could you help with the formula?

Comment: What have you tried?  Why not just use a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=query(A1:C,"where B <= date '2018-02-28' and (date '2018-02-01' <= C or C is null)",1)
```

[image]

Comment: if only the employee name is useful, add `select A ` before the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks, what I ended up using is your formula that is slightly updated: =query(A1:C,"Select A where B <= date '2019-08-31' and (B is NOT null) and (date '2019-08-1' <= C or C is null)",0)

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(A2:A,         B2:B  <=         DATE(2018, 2, 1), 
 IF(C2:C="", TODAY(), C2:C) >= EOMONTH(DATE(2018, 2, 1), 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want just `L M` use (eg. to remove blanks from C):

```
=FILTER(A2:A, B2:B <=         DATE(2018, 2, 1), 
              C2:C >= EOMONTH(DATE(2018, 2, 1), 0))
```